# копирование файлов centos 7

Tags: centos

здравствуйте, у меня есть папка с сайтом в /home/www/mywebsite

как можно скопировать всё что находится в директории mywebiste и вставить в /home/www/test?

Comment: google бы дал ответ быстрее )))

Answer (score 1):

:(

```
cp -r /home/www/mywebsite /home/www/test
```

если нет прав

```
sudo cp -r /home/www/mywebsite /home/www/test
```